# How to shorten a sentence with nested relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, style

I wrote:

> After calling the function on the child nodes, the *Match* function is called another time to match further rules. **This time, the rules which depend on the values of the variables set in the function calls are retrieved.**

I used a cascade of relative clauses. Is it normal to have such cascade in an article? How can I rephrase it so that it be shorter?
 as an extreme example consider

> the rules that depends on the variables set by the functions called on the strings given by a user who is assigned a task which is ....

Second, is it "in function calls" or "on function calls"?

Third, should I say ***variables set in the function calls*** or ***variables that might be set in the function calls***. Because maybe no variable is set in the function calls.

---

**Update:** I might be able to shortcut the dependency by:

> ...**This time, the rules whose (related, dependent, used) variables were set in the function calls are retrieved**

Comment: You think that's a long sentence?  It doesn't look so bad to me!  I think it's actually reasonably clear - the only thing I might change is to put "are retrieved" closer to "rules".

Comment: Ahmad, as a technical person I feel it's much nicer to use short declarative sentences, or even numbered lists of instructions where appropriate.  Unfortunately many people think it's good practice to use compound sentences like yours, which is why technical writing is often so tedious and abtruse.

Comment: @stangdon right, maybe awkward is a better description because several modifiers are used

Comment: Please note: call up or retrieve, but not just call. A calls up B; B is called up by A;

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Writing Advice are off-topic, as the Help Center (if that matters) says.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I agree, however, I added a more general case which matches the question title.

Answer (score 1):

Try **This time, the appropriate rules are retrieved, based on the values of the variables that were set in the function calls.**

Or **Rules are retrieved depending upon the values of variables set earlier**

Rather than using "variables that might be set in the function calls", you could use "variables set in the function calls, **if any.**"

Comment: Thank you, I also think I should start it with an active voice: *This time it retrieves the rules ....*